# Reducer not updating the state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

rootReducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import counterReducer from "./counter.reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: counterReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

counterReducer.js

```js
import { DECREMENT_COUNTER, INCREMENT_COUNTER } from "../Constants";
import initialState from "../initialState";

const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT_COUNTER: {
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter + 1
            }
        }
        
        case DECREMENT_COUNTER:
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter - 1
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default counterReducer
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { decrementCounter, incrementCounter } from './actions/counter.action';

function App() {
  const selector = useSelector(state => state)
  console.log(selector)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {selector.counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(incrementCounter())}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrementCounter())}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import initialState from "./initialState";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/root.reducer";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState: initialState
})

export default store
```

initialState.js

```
export const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}
```

So I'm trying to implement counter with increment and decrement button, but when I click on increment or decrement button it throughs me error stating

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {counter}).

I've tried console logging the state and I found that initially my state looks like

```
counter: 0
```

But when I click on the increment or decrement button state becomes

```
counter: {
  counter: NaN
}
```

I'm not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you are learning a pre-2019 style of Redux here - modern Redux looks very different. You might be following an outdated tutorial. For more info on legacy vs modern Redux, see https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Comment: @phry Thank you so much. Your response is useful to me but I'm still figuring out what is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

If the state is initially `counter: 0` then I suspect the `initialState` of the `counterReducer` is actually just something like `const initialState = 0;`. It would seem then the problem is your `counterReducer` function is injecting a nested `counter` property.

`state.counter` is undefined, and when you add/subtract it results in a `NaN`, and then all further math operations on `NaN` are `NaN`.

```js
const state = 0;

console.log({ state, "state.counter + 1": state.counter + 1 });
```

Once `state.counter` is mutated with the nested property, it becomes `state.counter.counter`. It's this `counter.counter` object that can't be rendered as JSX.

## Solution

Update `counterReducer` increment/decrement cases to add to or subtract from just `state` which is the counter value.

```js
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT_COUNTER:
      return state + 1;
        
    case DECREMENT_COUNTER:
      return state - 1;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In the UI you'll want to select the specific state you want to subscribe to. ***Don't*** write selector functions that return the entire state, e.g. don't use `useSelector(state => state);`.

```js
function App() {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(incrementCounter())}>
        Increment
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrementCounter())}>
        Decrement
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My initial state looks like `export const initialState = { counter: 0 }`. I have also included the initialState in question.

Comment: @CodeCreater Are you using the *same* `initialState` value for both the store ***and*** the `counterReducer`? The store's initial state would a subset of the combined reducers that make up your *entire* state object, the reducer's initial state should be *just that reducer's* state. If the global state has the shape `{ counter: 0 }` then the counter reducer's initial state would just be `0`. Does this make sense? Can you confirm if you are using the same `initialState` value in both places?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the same initialState for both store and reducer. So should I try with only `0` as initialState for reducer?

Comment: @CodeCreater Yes, that is my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks!! It is working and also found an alternate solution when I removed `preloadedState` from the store it works fine.